# Ошибка в задании шаблона?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, шаблоны-с++, g++

При сборке возникает ошибка:

```
#include <iostream>
const int DefaultSize=10;
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Array
{
  public:
    Array(int itsSize=DefaultSize);
    Array(const Array& rhs);
    ~Array() {delete [] pType;}

    Array& operator = (const Array&);
    T& operator[] (int offset){return pType[offset];}
    const T& operator [] (int offset) const {return pType[offset];}

    friend void Intrude(Array<int>);

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Array<T>&);  // < Компилятор указывает на 
    int GetSize() const {return itsSize;}              //эту строку

  private:
    T *pType;
    int itsSize;
};

template <class T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Array<T>& theArray)
{
  for (int i=0;i<theArray.GetSize();i++)
    output<< "["<<i<<"]"<<theArray[i]<<endl;
  return output;
}
```

**отчет во время компиляции:**

> g++ -Wall -c "template.cpp" (в каталоге: /host/projects/template)
> template.cpp:30:52: warning: friend declaration ‘std::ostream& >operator<<(std::ostream&, Array<t>&)’ declares a non-template function
> template.cpp:30:52: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function >template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)
> Сборка прошла успешно.

**отчет при сборке:**

> g++ -Wall -o "template" "template.cpp" (в каталоге: /host/projects/template)
> template.cpp:30:52: warning: friend declaration ‘std::ostream& >operator<<(std::ostream&, Array<t>&)’ declares a non-template function
> template.cpp:30:52: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function >template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)
> /tmp/cciPebmn.o: In function `main':
> template.cpp:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to >`operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char=""> >&, Array<int>&)'
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> Сборка завершилась с ошибкой.

Ну и собственно вопрос: **в чем ошибка?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
class Array
{
...
template <class X> friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& str, Array<X>& ar);
...
}

template <typename T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Array<T>& theArray)
{
  for (int i=0;i<theArray.GetSize();i++)
    output<< "["<<i<<"]"<<theArray[i]<<endl;
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, в описании класса перед

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Array<T>&);
```

надо поставить `template<class T>`:

```
template<class T>
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Array<T>&);
```

friend это ведь не метод, это такая хитрая глобальная декларация. Соответственно, классовый шаблон на него не действует.

Отмечу, что friend-декларация тут в принципе лишняя, ведь operator<< обращается только к публичным членам.

Comment: мимо. Имеем:
<precode>template.cpp:21:15: ошибка: declaration of ‘class T’
template.cpp:5:11: ошибка:  shadows template parm ‘class T’</precode>
Поэтому в моем ответе я использовал другое название для шаблонного класса :-)

Comment: Вы правы, конечно. Вместо T надо другое имя дать.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Array<T>&);
```

напишите:

```
friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream&, Array<T>&);
```

На gcc не проверял, но должно помочь.

Comment: теперь и на компиляции ошибку выдает:
template.cpp:30:21: error: template-id ‘operator<< <int>’ for ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Array<int>&)’ does not match any template declaration

Comment: Интересно. По ходу, тут действительно зависит от компилятора сильно. Мой вариант годится для MSVS. Тогда, вероятно, вариант от @gecube сможет помочь.

Comment: Да действительно

Comment: Тьху, ну, и смысл пользоваться шаблонами, коли везде они сделаны по-разному? По ходу, получается, что подмножество С++, которым можно безопасно пользоваться не такое уж и большое.
И если совсем честно, то в том примере, что я наворотил, я не совсем понимаю необходимость писать так как написано :-)

Comment: Странно, но описание функции как вложенной в классе есть альтернативный способ заставить все работать. Т.е. достаточно написать в описании класса:
<pre>friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, Array<T>& ar) < /\*blablabla\*/ return os;></pre>, удалить вынесенную отдельно операторную функцию и все начинает работать.

Answer (score 0):

Сам оператор

```
template <class T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Array<T>& theArray)
```

сделай инлайном:

```
template <class T> inline
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Array<T>& theArray)
```

Comment: Аналогично:
<pre>template.cpp:21:15: ошибка: declaration of ‘class T’
template.cpp:5:11: ошибка:  shadows template parm ‘class T’</pre>

Comment: Слушай, ну это вообще несерьезно. Совершенно непонятно что у тебя в каком файле лежит, а ты просишь что-то исправить, кидая ошибки с именами файла и строками вообще безо всяких пояснений. Либо приведи полный код с разбивкой на файлы и на то как ты их собираешь и какие ошибки возникают в итоге - либо боюсь нормального ответа на свой вопрос ты ни от кого не получишь в принципе.

Comment: Это излишне. См. исходный код автора - делаем указанные Вами правки. Получаем ошибку. А теперь вопрос - сами пробовали, прежде чем советовать?

Comment: Отож :)

    g++ --version
    g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3

полет нормальный. Только пришлось пустой main добавить, да грохнуть строчку

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Array<T>&);

Как явно лишнюю и от которой warnings. Но и с ней ошибок нет. Что я делаю не так?

Причем, оно натурально, даже с -Wall ничего не говорит. Отсюда собственно и вопросы к автору вопроса.

Comment: Ну, да. Опять же оказывается важным, чтобы 
<pre>template <class T> // здесь
class Array
{
...
template <class _T> friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Array<_T>&); // и здесь
...
}</pre>
название шаблона не совпадало.

Answer (score 0):

Вот код, все компилируется на gcc++ 4.4.3 и даже запускается. В чем вопрос?

```
~/tmp$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

~/tmp$ g++ template.cpp
~/tmp$ ./a.out
[0]0
[1]0
[2]0
[3]0
[4]0
[5]0
[6]0
[7]0
[8]0
[9]0
```

template.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
const int DefaultSize=10;
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Array
{
  public:
    Array(int s=DefaultSize) : itsSize(s), pType( new T[s] ) {}
    Array(const Array& rhs);
    ~Array() {delete [] pType;}

    Array& operator = (const Array&);
    T& operator[] (int offset){return pType[offset];}
    const T& operator [] (int offset) const {return pType[offset];}

    friend void Intrude(Array<int>);

    template <class _T> friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Array<_T>&);  // < Компилятор указывает на

    int GetSize() const {return itsSize;}              //эту строку

  private:
    T *pType;
    int itsSize;
};

template <class T> inline
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Array<T>& theArray)
{
  for (int i=0;i<theArray.GetSize();i++)
    output<< "["<<i<<"]"<<theArray[i]<<endl;
  return output;
}

int main()
{
    Array<double> xxx;
    cout << xxx << endl;
    return 0;
}
```